# Databricks notebook doesn't return value to caller notebook when using Structured Streaming query

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

My callee notebook is using structured streaming and then when the callee notebook is called from caller notebook. The callee notebook doesn't return any value to caller notebook.
Here you can see the code snippet which creates the problem.

here is my callee notebook

```scala
val query = data.writeStream.outputMode("append")
     .format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
     .option("mergeSchema", "true").trigger(Trigger.Once)
     .start(sinkPath)
    
dbutils.notebook.exit("Return something")
```

caller notebook calls this callee notebook and returns none even though callee notebook executes till end but exit message doesnt return to caller notebook.
Does anybody have any idea or experience similar issue?

Comment: for me it looks like a "feature", because streaming notebooks could be handled differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "feature" caused by specifics of implementation of structured streaming support in the Databricks notebooks. This happens even if you're using `Trigger.Once`, and expect that job will be finished.

If you need to return some data from the notebook, you can create global temp view, or something like.  If you need to return data for logging purposes, then it's better to log directly from notebook.  One of the reasons for that is that the amount of data that could be returned back is limited (I don't remember, maybe 1k of ascii characters)